# Como pegar o ID de um usuário em uma ListView e usar como uma variável em outra Activity?

Tags: java, android, array

Estou fazendo meu TCC e estou tendo dificuldades em retirar o ID de algum usuário da ListView e usá-lo em outra Activity (A intenção é que quando o usuário segurar o clique em cima de alguém da lista, apareça uma popup (popAdd) perguntando se ele deseja enviar uma solicitação de amizade para essa pessoa (E pra isso eu preciso de saber o ID da pessoa escolhida)

popAddAmigo.java

```
public class popAddAmigo extends Activity {

String urlAddress="http://192.168.1.107/line/Pesquisa.php";
// String urlAddress="http://172.16.2.15/line/Pesquisa.php";
SearchView sv;
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.popaddamigo);

    lv           = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaAmigos);
    sv           = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.svPesquisa);

    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            SenderReceiver sr = new SenderReceiver(popAddAmigo.this, urlAddress, query, lv);
            sr.execute();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            SenderReceiver sr = new SenderReceiver(popAddAmigo.this, urlAddress, query, lv);
            sr.execute();
            return false;
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       final int pos, long id) {


            Intent abreAdd = new Intent(popAddAmigo.this, popAdd.class);
            startActivity(abreAdd);





            return false;
        }
    });

}

}
```

Parser.java

```
public class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer> {

Context c;
String data;
ListView lv;

ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

public Parser(Context c, String data, ListView lv) {

    this.c    = c;
    this.data = data;
    this.lv   = lv;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.parse();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
    super.onPostExecute(integer);

    if(integer==1) {

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(c,R.layout.listalayout,names);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(c,"Não encontramos resultado :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

private int parse() {

    try {

        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);
        JSONObject jo = null;
        names.clear();

        for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++) {
            jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = jo.getString("nome");
            names.add(name);

        }
        return 1;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

SenderReceiver.java

```
public class SenderReceiver extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

Context c;
String urlAddress;
String query;
ListView lv;
ProgressDialog pd;

public SenderReceiver(Context c, String urlAddress, String query, ListView lv,ImageView...imageViews) {

    this.c = c;
    this.urlAddress = urlAddress;
    this.query = query;
    this.lv = lv;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {

    super.onPreExecute();
    pd=new ProgressDialog(c);
    pd.setTitle("Pesquisando...");
    pd.setMessage("Por favor aguarde.");
    pd.show();

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return this.sendAndReceive();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);

    pd.dismiss();

    lv.setAdapter(null);

    if(s != null) {
        if(!s.contains("null")) {

            Parser p = new Parser(c,s,lv);
            p.execute();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(), "Usuário não encontrado.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(c.getApplicationContext(), "Nenhuma conexão com a Internet foi encontrada.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

private String sendAndReceive()
{
    HttpURLConnection con = Connector.connect(urlAddress);

    if(con==null) {
        return null;
    } try {

        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
        bw.write(new DataPackager(query).packageData());
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
        os.close();
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        if(responseCode==con.HTTP_OK) {

            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            if(br != null) {
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line+"n");
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
            return response.toString();
        } else {
            return String.valueOf(responseCode);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

DataPackager.java

```
public class DataPackager {

String query;

public DataPackager(String query) {
    this.query = query;
}

public String packageData() {

    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer();

    try {

        jo.put("Query",query);
        Boolean firstValue = true;
        Iterator it = jo.keys();

        do {
            String key = it.next().toString();
            String value = jo.get(key).toString();
            if(firstValue) {
                firstValue = false;
            } else {
                queryString.append("&");
            }

            queryString.append(URLEncoder.encode(key,"UTF-8"));
            queryString.append("=");
            queryString.append(URLEncoder.encode(value,"UTF-8"));

        } while (it.hasNext());

        return queryString.toString();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: Sua classe `Parser` está com o conteúdo da `SenderReceiver`. Pode atualizá-la?

Comment: Pronto, ja atualizei

Comment: Dentro do método `parse()` do seu `Parser`, você tem um JSONObject `jo`. Dentro dele você tem o id do usuário também ou somente o nome?
Igual no `jo.getString("nome")`, só que você faria `jo.getString("id")`

Comment: Somente o nome, então se eu fizer com o id vai dar certo? Tentei aqui e nada..

Comment: Não. Só com o id também não vai funcionar, mas precisa dos dois. Já vou atualizar a resposta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro do método `onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, ...)` você deve obter o usuário e passá-lo dentro da intent para iniciar a activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View arg1, final int pos, long id) {

    /*
    Converte do tipo Object para o tipo que você 
    passou no seu adapter, por exemplo:
    */
    Usuario usuario = (Usuario) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(pos);

    Intent abreAdd = new Intent(popAddAmigo.this, popAdd.class);
    // Aqui você passa o id para a intent, com a chave "idUsuario"
    abreAdd.putExtra("idUsuario", usuario.getId());
    startActivity(abreAdd);

    return true;
}
```

popAdd.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pop_add);

    // Obtém o id do usuário
    int idUsuario = getIntent().getIntExtra("idUsuario", 0);
}
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Você vai precisar de uma classe `Usuario` para armazenar as informações dele. No seu caso, seria o id e o nome.

Usuario.java

```
public class Usuario {
    private int id;
    private String nome;

    public Usuario(JSONObject object) {
        id = object.getInt("id");
        nome = object.getString("nome");
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

Você também vai precisar de uma classe customizada para exibir o usuário na lista.

ExampleAdapter.java

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Usuario> {
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;

    private List<Usuario> usuarioList;

    public ExampleAdapter(@NonNull Context context, List<Usuario> usuarioList) {
        super(context, R.layout.listalayout);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.usuarioList = usuarioList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Aqui você tem que verificar se o convertView está nulo,
        // porque pode acontecer de ele ser nulo
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listalayout, parent, false);
        }

        Usuario usuario = getItem(position);

        TextView txtNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_nome);

        txtNome.setText(usuario.getNome());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Usuario getItem(int position) {
        return usuarioList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return usuarioList == null ? 0 : usuarioList.size();
    }
}
```

E por último altera o seu `Parser` para processar uma lista de `Usuarios` ao invés de `Strings`.

Parser.java

```
public class Parser extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Integer> {

    Context c;
    String data;
    ListView lv;

    ArrayList<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<>();

    public Parser(Context c, String data, ListView lv) {

        this.c    = c;
        this.data = data;
        this.lv   = lv;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return this.parse();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);

        if(integer==1) {

            ExampleAdapter adapter = new ExampleAdapter(c,usuarios);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(c,"Não encontramos resultado :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

    private int parse() {

        try {

            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);
            usuarios.clear();

            for(int i=0;i<ja.length();i++) {
                usuarios.add(new Usuario(ja.getJSONObject(i)));

            }
            return 1;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65185/discussion-on-answer-by-danilo-de-oliveira-como-pegar-o-id-de-um-usuario-em-uma)